# Why is Groovy not converting an array of Strings into JSON correctly?

Tags: arrays, json, groovy

I have a String that has an array of Strings which I converted that into a groovy array (with the split function), and then I am using `JsonOutput.toJson` to convert that array into JSON like so.

```
def orignal = "[  \"Backsplash\",  \"Kitchen Wall\",  \"Wall Tile\",  \"Bathroom Wall\"]"
def originalAsArray = orignal.toString().split(",")
JsonOutput.toJson(originalAsArray)
```

The output of this is

```
["[  \"Backsplash\"","  \"Kitchen Wall\"","  \"Wall Tile\"","  \"Bathroom Wall\"]"]
```

which is an array with a single String element where I was expecting an element with multiple String elements like so

```
[  "Backsplash",  "Kitchen Wall","  "Wall Tile","  "Bathroom Wall"]
```

Why is the array not being converted as I expected?

Comment: "_which is an array with a single String element_", it's not, it's a list with 4 elements.  It's the input string chopped into 4 (at the location of a comma)

Answer (score 1):

```
// Given the original String
def original = '[  "Backsplash",  "Kitchen Wall",  "Wall Tile",  "Bathroom Wall"]'

// The easiest way of parsing it (as it's valid JSON already)
def list = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parseText(original)

// And we get a list of Strings:
assert list.size() == 4
assert list[0] == 'Backsplash'
assert list[3] == 'Bathroom Wall'

// To put this back into a JSON string, we just need to do:
def output = groovy.json.JsonOutput.toJson(list)

// Which gives us the string as expected:
assert output == '["Backsplash","Kitchen Wall","Wall Tile","Bathroom Wall"]'
```